# ¿Como obtener todos los registros a través de una tabla pivote?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

estoy tratando de obtener los datos de todos los artistas por su género para una api, para ello los tengo en una tabla pivote, al tomar los datos antes de entrar en el foreach vienen correctos, pero el return solo me da 1 resultado y los necesito todos... alguna ayuda por favor?

```
    public function genre_artist ( ApiArtistGenreRequest $request)
{

    $genre = Genre::where('name', '=', $request->genre)->first();

        if ( $genre ) {

            $genres_artists = GenreArtist::where('genre_id', '=', $genre->id)->get();
         
            //TODO: solo me está devolviendo 1
                foreach( $genres_artists as $item ){

                    $artists = Artist::where('id', '=', $item->artist_id)->paginate($request->per_page);

                     return $this->prepareResult(true, $artists, [], "Artists for genres");
                }

        }

        else{
            return $this->prepareResult(true, '', [], "No Artists");
        }

}
```

Modelo Artist:

```
    public $translatedAttributes = ['title', 'description'];
protected $fillable = ['name', 'popularity', 'spotify_id', 'spotify_img', 'spotify_url', 'tracks_imported'];

public function genres ()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Genre', 'genre_artists')
        ->withPivot('artist_id');
}

public function tracks ()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Track', 'artist_track')
        ->withPivot('artist_id');
}
```

Modelo Genre:

```
    public $translatedAttributes = ['title'];
protected $fillable = ['name', 'popularity'];

public function artists ()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Artist', 'genre_artists')
        ->withPivot('genre_id');
}
```

Modelo pivote:

```
   protected $table = 'genre_artists';

protected $fillable = ['artist_id', 'genre_id'];
```

He intentado utilizar las relaciones pero no me aclaro...

Comment: Si, en esa tabla pivote tengo todo relacionado por sus id, artista y género

Comment: de todos los artistas que pertenecen a ese género

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando estás trabajando con una relación muchos a muchos, no necesitas crear un modelo para la tabla pivote, pues para construir las consultas estrán usando las otras 2 entidades vinculadas y las relaciones que provee Eloquent (*donde como segundo argumento declaras el nombre de la tabla pivote*).

De acuerdo con la información que proporcionas en los comentarios, si lo que buscas es obtener los artistas vinculados a un género, entonces ocupas:

- Invocar al modelo `Genre`
- Hacer una carga ambiciosa del modelo antes mencionado con sus registros relacionados a través de la relación `artists`
- Usa el método `where` para filtrar de todos los géneros solo aquel cuyo nombre coincida por el valor que llega por el `$request` y que compararemos contra la columna `name` de la tabla `genres`
- Encadenamos al final el método `first()`
- Elimina el modelo que creaste para la tabla pivote, no es necesario y no lo vas a ocupar

Consulta:

```
$genero = Genre::with('artists')->whereName($request->genre)->first();
```

Ahora si solo quieres los géneros que si tienen al menos un artista relacionado, puedes ocupar el método `has` así:

```
$genero = Genre::has('artists')->with('artists')->whereName($request->genre)->first();
```

Te recomiendo [leer esta sección](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models) para que estés al tanto de las reglas si decides si crear un modelo para la tabla intermedia.

Comment: Oh, vale, lo organizaré así, pero el resultado para el return deben ser todos los artistas que pertenecen a el género que le pasaré por el $request->genre... como lo hago?

Comment: En la tabla pivote tengo genre_id que liga con los artist_id que le toca

Comment: Ah, perdona, es 'name'

Comment: Wowwww, fantásticoo!! funciona perfectoo! Muchas grácias @BetaM